# String Arrays In Turbo Assembler

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16, tasm

How do I create an array of strings in Turbo Assembler and use indexes to get a specific value in it?
Here is my code:

```
strs db 
     'Shirt$'
     'Pants$'
     'Socks$'
```

When I try to run it, I get an "Illegal Instruction" error

Comment: Maybe you want an array of pointers to strings? Create 3 separate strings and put the offsets (addresses) in an array.

Comment: You forgot the commas between operands.  Presumably that's an assemble-time syntax error, not a runtime #UD exception you're talking about?  Having `'Pants$'` by itself on a line might be valid if the previous line ends with a `,` but I don't know.  You might want a separate `db` on each line.  (And of course this is only viable without a table of pointers if all strings are the same length, or you can pad them so they are.)

Answer (score 3):

You first should think about what a "string array" is:

```
strs db 'Shirt$'
     db 'Pants$'
     db 'Socks$'
```

(By the way: The `db` was in the wrong location in your code!)

... is the same as:

```
strs db 'Shirt$Pants$Socks$'
```

A "string" means that some bytes in memory hold values that can be interpreted as ASCII characters.

```
strs db 'Shirt$'
```

... means:

The byte at the address `strs` has the value representing the character `S`, the byte at the address `strs+1` has the value representing the character `h` and so on.

You first have to think about what you actually want to have. You **might** say:

"*Each entry in my array shall be able to hold a string up to 20 characters length (21 including the dollar sign).*"

In this case you **might** decide that the memory locations `strs`...`strs+20` hold the first string, the locations `strs+21`...`strs+41` the second one and `strs+42`...`strs+62` the third one.

This would look like this:

```
strs db 'Shirt$xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxPants$xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxSocks$xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

... which is the same as:

```
strs db 'Shirt$xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
     db 'Pants$xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
     db 'Socks$xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

... and the same as:

```
strs       db 'Shirt$'
strsspare1 db 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
strs2      db 'Pants$'
strsspare2 db 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
strs3      db 'Socks$'
strsspare3 db 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Answer (score 3):

While the other answer is correct, if one assumes that the concept of an array of strings is similar to a high level language like *C* then really you are dealing with arrays of pointers (offsets) to strings elsewhere in memory. You can create an array of these offsets (pointers) to the strings themselves.

As an example a *C* program might define an array this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *strarray[] = { "Shirt$", "Pants$", "Socks$" };
    printf("%s", strarray[2]);
    printf("%s", strarray[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The following is functionally equivalent but we have named the strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *str1 = "Shirt$";
    char *str2 = "Pants$";
    char *str3 = "Socks$";

    char *strarray[] = { str1, str2, str3 };
    printf("%s", strarray[2]);
    printf("%s", strarray[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The latter example I will use for reproducing similar code in 16-bit assembly. It makes it easier to compare the assembly code with the *C* code.

The following is a 16-bit DOS program in MASM/TASM/JWASM assembly language that creates 3 separate strings and creates an array of pointers (offsets) to each of the strings. It then indexes the pointer array to get the address of the strings to print. This example shows 2 techniques for accessing the array. One where the index is encoded in the memory operand and the other has the index placed in a register (`BX` in this case).

```
.model small
.stack 256

.data
str1 DB 'Shirt$'
str2 DB 'Pants$'
str3 DB 'Socks$'

; Create an array of pointers (offsets) to the strings in memory
strarray DW OFFSET str1, OFFSET str2, OFFSET str3

.code

start:
    ; Setup the DS register to point at .data
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    ; TYPE operator returns the size of an element in strarray.
    ; 2 in this case since we defined strarray with elements
    ; of type word (DW)

    ; Get the pointer stored in 3rd element of strarray to DX
    mov dx, strarray[2*(TYPE strarray)]

    ; Print the string using DOS function call
    mov ah, 9h
    int 21h

    ; Alternatively you can access the array element through
    ; a register like BX, SI, DI

    ; Get the offset of the 2nd element into BX
    mov bx, 1*(TYPE strarray)
    ; Get the pointer stored in 2nd element of strarray to DX
    mov dx, strarray[bx]

    ; Print the string using DOS function call
    mov ah, 9h
    int 21h

    ; Exit program
    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h

end start
```

With MASM's x86 Intel syntax the memory operands appear like array indexes but they aren't. The value between `[]` is the index in BYTES. As a result you always have to multiply the index by the size of the elements in the array. `NEAR` pointers are 2 bytes in 16-bit code so the byte index of each element has to be multiplied by 2. In the code above I use the [`TYPE`](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Instructions/I77_0140_type_lengthof_sizeof.htm) operator that returns the size of an array element. `strarray` is defined as a `DW` (16-bit word array) so returns the value 2 since each element is 2 bytes in size.

The output of this code would be:

> ```
> SocksPants
> ```